# avaudiorecorder does not save file anymore after segue and back

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, avaudiorecorder

Here is the sequence of what I do :

- instantiate AVAudioRecorder with settings and `fileUrl = "soundUrl"`
- `prepareToRecord()`
- record when a button is pressed (recordButton)
- reset recording when another button (restartButton) is pressed (this is a call to `prepareToRecord()` with the same recorder instance)

This works fine in the simulator and on my device, but for some reason when I segue to a view in a navigation controller and then go back, the recorder does not record anymore (file is empty) but only on the device, not in the simulator where it is just fine!
The delegate methods do not send any error, `prepareToRecord()` Looks to be working fine, and my testFlight users are having the problem.

I also tried re-instantiating the `AVAudioRecorder` instead of just `prepareToRecord()`, but the problem stays the same.

Has anyone had the same or a similar issue?
I will edit the post with code if you need it.

Comment: try writing the instantiate code in recordButton()

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but the result is the same, I will try to provide more info and code!